# Visual state chart editor

Tags: xml, state-machine, scxml

Is there a tool similar to [Eclipse Based Visual SCXML Editor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-scxml/download_scxml.cgi) for constructing Harel State Tables? Currently the status in the project page is code unreleased. how do i install the plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this tool, which appears to be under active development: http://code.google.com/p/scxmlgui/

For a commercial tool, MagicDraw supports drawing UML state machines, as well as graphically simulating them using their Cameo Simulation Toolkit and the Apache Commons SCXML project: https://www.nomagic.com/products/magicdraw

Comment: thanks for the link. The page shows how to download the code and then get in running. How can I get the plugin running without compiling code like using the eclipse c++ plugin?

Comment: That page provides the most concise instructions available. Because the code is unreleased, ASF does not host builds of the plugin, so you need to build it yourself. However, this is done automatically by eclipse when you import it into your workspace. If you have further questions, you may want to ask on the Apache Commons User mailing list. I think the author is still on the list. Just prefix the subject with [scxml-eclipse].

Comment: The author's original first link appears to be dead, so I edited it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a (free) open-source extension for VS Code which lets you edit your SCXML file in XML and visually at the same time: [Visual SCXML Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Phrogz.visual-scxml-editor)

[image]

The *eventual*, pipe-dream goal might be a visual editor that is full-featured enough to stand on its own: to let you fully inspect and edit all aspects of a statechart without ever touching the XML. That's not the current goal, though. The near-term goal (mostly achieved) is to allow you to reason about a statechart visually, and clean up the visuals (moving things around) using graphical editing wherever it is appropriate.

All feature requests and TODO items are [tracked on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Phrogz/visual-scxml-editor/issues); if the plugin is missing a feature you desire, please add it there.